# Lista de objetos, ingresar otra lista de objetos

Tags: java, lista

Tengo una lista

```
List<Usuario> = new ArayList<Usuario>();
```

`Usuario` siendo una clase. Quiero añadir a esta lista otra lista de un `Invitado`, siendo esta también una clase, pero no se como crear la lista de Invitado dentro de la lista Usuario,

¿Como puedo añadir esa lista Invitado?

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Te invito a hacer el [tour] para aprender sobre el funcionamiento del sitio y a leer [ask]. No me queda claro si lo que tu quieres es que cada `Usuario` tenga su lista de `Invitado`, o si en una misma lista quieres tener usuarios e invitados mezclados.

Comment: Si, eso quiero. Quiero que casa usuario tenga una lista de invitados.

Comment: Sugiero entonces que edites tu pregunta y lo dejes en claro allí. Haz eso cada vez que aclares dudas sobre la pregunta, la idea es que la perfecciones. Un saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entendiendo que quieres que cada `Usuario` tenga una lista de `Invitados`, vas a tener que crear un atributo en tu clase `Usuario` que sea, por ejemplo:

```
public class Usuario {

    private List<Invitados> invitados = new ArrayList<Invitados>;

    public void setInvitado(Invitados invitado) {
        this.invitados.add(invitado);
    }
    //Otros metodos para obtener Invitados, obtener la lista... lo que quieras
}
```

Entonces, si quieres añadir invitados a tu lista de usuario tendras que recorrer, por ejemplo, con un `for-each` la lista de usuarios y para cada uno de ellos, añadir a un `Invitado`, por ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Otra manera es  con Set y HashSet:

```
public class Usuario {

    private Set<Invitado> invitados = new Hashset<>() ;
    public void setInvitados(Invitado invitado) {
        invitados.add(invitado);
   } 
}
```

Volviendo al ejemplo con List() 
Tendrías que crear cada invitado tal que:

```
Invitado invitado1 = new Invitado(1, "invitado1", "apellido1") ;//según constructor
```

Y después agregarselo a un Usuario existente:

```
Usuario u = new Usuario(); //según constructor
u.setInvitados(invitado1);
```

Si lo que quieres es que recorra la lista usuarios y que agregue la misma lista de invitados se podria hacer algo así.

```
private List<Invitado> invitados =new Arraylis<Invitado>() ;
//se rellenaria con los datos  de tipo Invitados
private List <Usuario> usuario = new ArrayList<Usuario>() ;
//rellena con los datos de tipo Usuario

for(Usuario u : usuarios) {
   for(Invitado i : invitados) {
       u.setInvitados(i);
   } 
}
```

Otra opción es que crees un metodo del tipo setInvitados pero que reciba una lista completa del tipo:

```
public void setInvitadosLista (List<Invitados> invitados) {
    this.invitados = invitados;
}
```

Entonces, usando la lista invitados anteriormente declarada:

```
for(Usuario u : usuarios) {
       u.setInvitadosLista(invitados) ;
}
```